# Accessing file from python code in databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I am trying to access a model file I had previously copied over via CLI by using the following code in a notebook at https://community.cloud.databricks.com/

```
with open("/dbfs/cat_encoder.joblib", "rb") as f:
    lb_category = joblib.load(f)
```

For this I get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/cat_encoder.joblib'
```

I had copied the file using the CLI as I said by running:

```
dbfs cp cat_encoder.joblib dbfs:/cat_encoder.joblib
```

Then doing

```
databricks fs ls "dbfs:/"
```

I see the file which I had copied.

But if I were to do this in my notebook:

```
os.chdir('/dbfs')
print(os.listdir('.'))
```

I see an empty directory instead of the folder and files I see if I were using the UI or the CLI.

If I were to do a write into this empty directory from the notebook, yes that works and I would see exactly one file in that directory the file I had just written, the problem is I want to read what I had already put there beforehand.

It looks as if the local api cannot see what the proverbial other hand is doing with all the datasets and models I have loaded either by CLI or by UI. So why can I not see these files? Does it have something to do with credentials, and if so how do I resolve that? Or is likely something entirely else like maybe mounting?  I am doing an introductory trial and some basic stuff on my own to learn databricks, so I am not too familiar with the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a behavior change in the Databricks Runtime 7.x on the Community Edition (and only there) - the `dbfs:/` files aren't available anymore via `/dbfs/...`. If you want to access that DBFS file locally then you can use `dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/file', 'file:/local-path')` (or `%fs cp ...`) to copy file from DBFS to local file system where you can work with it.

Comment: When you mention 'file:///local-path', what is concrete example of this? Would it be 'file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads"' or something? Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: local path here means path on the driver node of the cluster, like, `file:/tmp/my-test-file`

Comment: Ahh, I wrongfully assumed local was referencing local machine. Do you know if that is possible? I've not come across any resources sharing how to directly save to desktop from a databricks notebook.

Comment: There is no way to do that - databricks cluster is running somewhere in the cloud, usually in isolated environment. Potentially you can upload file from DBFS into S3, for example, and then download it via command-line or UI.  Another way is to put the file into `FileStore` on DBFS and download it via `/files/` link (see docs: https://docs.databricks.com/data/filestore.html#save-a-file-to-filestore), but I'm not sure if it works on community edition

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out about 3 problems downstream, but now it works for me.  The problem I was trying to solve was to save a ClassifierDL model of spark-nlp and the help out I got on this one solved many problems simultaneously for me.

Within databricks, I created a new cluster and in the spark configuration section I added the following 2 lines:

```
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 1000M
spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

After starting the client, I was able to read locally using '/dbfs/cat_encoder.joblib' as I had intended in the above code.